# How to send a Confidential email using VBScript

Tags: vbscript, exchange-server, cdo.message, confidential

I have been searching on-line on how to send an email with attachment as confidential. I was already able to create a script to be able to send an email with an attachment but I can't figure out how to send it as confidential.

I would appreciate if somebody can help me how to set email sensitivity in VBScript.

Here's my code:

```
Call Email

sub Email

    Set objEmail = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    objEmail.From = "myemail"
    objEmail.To = "SendToEmail"
    ObjEmail.Subject = "Email Title"
    ObjEmail.Textbody = "Email Body"
    objEmail.AddAttachment "C:\Temp\ERSD\dchmar_" & sDate & ".txt"
    objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
    objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") ="xx.xx.xx.xx"
    objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25
    objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/sensitivity") = 3
    objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Update
    objEmail.Send

End sub
```

Comment: I think to to that you will need to set [Mail Headers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms988660%28v=exchg.65%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) specifically [`urn:schemas:mailheader:sensitivity`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms875171(v=exchg.65).aspx) using one of the [`cdoSensitivityValues` Enum](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms870469(v=exchg.65).aspx) values. Show us a [mcve] of what you have so far by [editing the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37668956/edit) and we will try and help. Also might be worth reading [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try this?

It's unknown if you have some custom headers. So check the headers in Outlook to see if those match with what I've posted below but I believe that should accomplish what you're asking.

```
Set objEmail = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
Set objEmailConf = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
objEmail.From = "myemail"
objEmail.To = "SendToEmail"
ObjEmail.Subject = "Email Title"
ObjEmail.Textbody = "Email Body"
objEmail.AddAttachment "C:\Temp\ERSD\dchmar_" & sDate & ".txt"
objEmailConf.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
objEmailConf.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") ="xx.xx.xx.xx"
objEmailConf.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25
'objEmailConf.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/sensitivity") = 3
objEmailConf.Fields.Update
objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item("urn:schemas:mailheader:Sensitivity") = "Company-Confidential"
objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Update
objEmail.Send
```